Why does df.means() cause "Javascript Error: too much recursion" in Jupyter?
I am doing some ML-Training on the pump_sensor_data from Kaggle:https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/nphantawee/pump-sensor-data
(Instructions for Analysis of the Data for Reference: https://www.kaggle.com/code/pinakimishrads/anomaly-detection-for-time-series-sensor-data)
For Data Cleaning I want to do the following:
In:
import pandas as pd
sensors = pd.read_csv('pump_sensor.csv')
sensors.fillna(sensors.mean(),inplace= True)

Out:
Javascript Error: too much recursion

I also tried:
In:
means = sensors.mean(axis=0, skipna=True)

But got the same error.
What's wrong here?
I also exceeded the Recursion Limit to above the Number of Rows with no Effect. So I guess the Error is not caused by Python (as also "Javascript Error" indicates)
I am using Jupyter Notebook on Windows with Firefox.
Additional Info:
In:
sensors.shape
Out:
(220320, 51)

In:
sensors.head()
Out:
    sensor_00   sensor_01   sensor_02   sensor_03   sensor_04   sensor_05   sensor_06   sensor_07   sensor_08   sensor_09   sensor_10   sensor_11   sensor_12   sensor_13   sensor_14   sensor_16   sensor_17   sensor_18   sensor_19   sensor_20   sensor_21   sensor_22   sensor_23   sensor_24   sensor_25   sensor_26   sensor_27   sensor_28   sensor_29   sensor_30   sensor_31   sensor_32   sensor_33   sensor_34   sensor_35   sensor_36   sensor_37   sensor_38   sensor_39   sensor_40   sensor_41   sensor_42   sensor_43   sensor_44   sensor_45   sensor_46   sensor_47   sensor_48   sensor_49   sensor_51   machine_status
timestamp                                                                                                                                                                                                           
2018-04-01 00:00:00     2.465394    47.09201    53.2118     46.310760   634.3750    76.45975    13.41146    16.13136    15.56713    15.05353    37.22740    47.52422    31.11716    1.681353    419.5747    461.8781    466.3284    2.565284    665.3993    398.9862    880.0001    498.8926    975.9409    627.6740    741.7151    848.0708    429.0377    785.1935    684.9443    594.4445    682.8125    680.4416    433.7037    171.9375    341.9039    195.0655    90.32386    40.36458    31.51042    70.57291    30.98958    31.770832   41.92708    39.641200   65.68287    50.92593    38.194440   157.9861    67.70834    201.3889    NORMAL
2018-04-01 00:01:00     2.465394    47.09201    53.2118     46.310760   634.3750    76.45975    13.41146    16.13136    15.56713    15.05353    37.22740    47.52422    31.11716    1.681353    419.5747    461.8781    466.3284    2.565284    665.3993    398.9862    880.0001    498.8926    975.9409    627.6740    741.7151    848.0708    429.0377    785.1935    684.9443    594.4445    682.8125    680.4416    433.7037    171.9375    341.9039    195.0655    90.32386    40.36458    31.51042    70.57291    30.98958    31.770832   41.92708    39.641200   65.68287    50.92593    38.194440   157.9861    67.70834    201.3889    NORMAL
2018-04-01 00:02:00     2.444734    47.35243    53.2118     46.397570   638.8889    73.54598    13.32465    16.03733    15.61777    15.01013    37.86777    48.17723    32.08894    1.708474    420.8480    462.7798    459.6364    2.500062    666.2234    399.9418    880.4237    501.3617    982.7342    631.1326    740.8031    849.8997    454.2390    778.5734    715.6266    661.5740    721.8750    694.7721    441.2635    169.9820    343.1955    200.9694    93.90508    41.40625    31.25000    69.53125    30.46875    31.770830   41.66666    39.351852   65.39352    51.21528    38.194443   155.9606    67.12963    203.7037    NORMAL
2018-04-01 00:03:00     2.460474    47.09201    53.1684     46.397568   628.1250    76.98898    13.31742    16.24711    15.69734    15.08247    38.57977    48.65607    31.67221    1.579427    420.7494    462.8980    460.8858    2.509521    666.0114    399.1046    878.8917    499.0430    977.7520    625.4076    739.2722    847.7579    474.8731    779.5091    690.4011    686.1111    754.6875    683.3831    446.2493    166.4987    343.9586    193.1689    101.04060   41.92708    31.51042    72.13541    30.46875    31.510420   40.88541    39.062500   64.81481    51.21528    38.194440   155.9606    66.84028    203.1250    NORMAL
2018-04-01 00:04:00     2.445718    47.13541    53.2118     46.397568   636.4583    76.58897    13.35359    16.21094    15.69734    15.08247    39.48939    49.06298    31.95202    1.683831    419.8926    461.4906    468.2206    2.604785    663.2111    400.5426    882.5874    498.5383    979.5755    627.1830    737.6033    846.9182    408.8159    785.2307    704.6937    631.4814    766.1458    702.4431    433.9081    164.7498    339.9630    193.8770    101.70380   42.70833    31.51042    76.82291    30.98958    31.510420   41.40625    38.773150   65.10416    51.79398    38.773150   158.2755    66.55093    201.3889    NORMAL


if you use a semicolon after the last command to suppress output, does it run without error?

maybe problem is not in your code but maybe kaggle has some mistake on server - and you have to wait until they fix it.

@joe: Unfortunately no. Does not change anything

did you test page with other browser? Chrome, Edge, Opera?

@furas: I am running locally on my Laptop (Win, JupyterNB, Firefox)

still you can test it on different browsers.

Javascript Error in python code ?  are you debugging using javascript ?

@furas: tried Chrome.
"means = sensors.mean(axis=0, skipna=True)" is runnig like for ever. I aborted after 15 Mins.

@D.L: No. It is just the Jupyter Notbook in Firefox.

As Chrome is not raising the Javascript error but asking frequently to leave the Page, as Jupyter does not seem to react during Computation, I guess that both Browsers react to the extreme long computation Time in their own way.
So the Guess is: Firefox raises the Error as Reaction to an extreme long Computation.

What is sensors.shape?

Can you include sensors.head() in your question?

I run code on Kaggle and sometimes I get this error for vals = df.mean() because it runs very, very long. But it runs fast (without error) for df.mean(numeric_only=True)

@furas: That seemed to did the Trick. And it was incredible fast.
Makes sense also, as the Column "machine_status" is String. So df.mean() might cause some Problems with that.

I found it maybe because I run df.describe() which also calculate mean and it runs fast, and I knew that it shows values only for numeric columns.

Can you edit your question to provide information on the notebook server version (!jupyter notebook --version ), pandas version (%pip show pandas) and the ipykernel version (%pip show ipykernel)?

As @furas wrote df.mean(numeric_only=True)  fastened the Computation sufficiently. One none numerical Column was Part of the Data.
As a Result the Java Script Error was not thrown by Firefox.
Guesses for Javascript Error:

only occurred in Firefox
did not occur in Chrome, but Computation was long and did not finish. Chrome reacted with "Page not reacting" Message though.

So as a Conclusion the Java Script Error is related to the Browser (Firefox).
If Firefox could be set up to not throw this Error via about:config or similar is not answered.
